# HTTPS Web API and Android

Tags: android, https, wcf-web-api

I have built a RESTful web service using Microsoft Web API framework. I've been able to test the service from my computer and other computers of my network (using the browser). But when I try to hit my web service from Android, nothing happens. Well, yes, something is happening, but not right. I am using a self-signed certificate. I have tried several approaches I found here to manage self-signed certificates in Android... but everyone fails somehow. Some throw the "No peer certificate" exception and others just get an "Internal server error" response. I have added a breakpoint to the first line of my web service, but the program never reaches it. So something is happening low-level.

Any ideas? :(